# What is the correct way to call rust code in C in windows?

Tags: gcc, rust, ffi

I am trying to call a simple rust function from C to explore rust FFI. I was following a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFFbTeU25pE&t=5108s) on the topic by Ryan Levick but running into some problems. Below is my code-

lib.rs

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn get_string() -> *const u8 {
    b"Hello C World\0".as_ptr()
}
```

cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "hello-c-world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern const char *get_string(void);
int main()
{
    char *string = get_string();
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

First, I ran `cargo build --release` which produced a target\release folder
[image]

I am able to see get_string method when i do objdump
[image]

However, When I am trying to create the executable to run, it's not able to find the target library. I think I am making a basic mistake here. Can someone please help out in getting the right gcc command to call get_string? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You'll need to declare your rust function with `pub extern "C" fn ...`

Comment: While this is in the embedded context, it's some good info on C interop: https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/rust-with-c.html

Comment: Umm, you're using `-I` for the library (the character after H, if font issues), when it should be `-l` (lowercase L, the letter after K if font issues).  At the least, that's an issue.  Your linker warning even says that: not a directory, because `-I` is for include directories.

Comment: here are the docs for doing FFI https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#calling-rust-code-from-c

Comment: [Please remove the images of text and replace them with their contents (as text)](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

- *lib.rs*:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_string() -> *const u8 {
    b"Hello C World\0".as_ptr()
}
```

- *Cargo.toml*:

```ini
[package]
name = "hello-c-world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

Then, do

```
cargo build --release
```

This should produce the file `target/release/libhello_c_world.a`.

Note I am on a Linux system, so your `.a` might be a `.lib`. The rest should be similar.

- *main.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern const char *get_string(void);

int main()
{
    const char *string = get_string();
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Then, in the folder where `main.c` lies, do:

```
gcc -L./target/release/ -o my_main main.c -lhello_c_world
```

where `./target/release/` must be the folder where `libhello_c_world.a` is in. In my case `main.c` lies next to `Cargo.toml`, so this path is correct, but of course adjust it if your `main.c` is somewhere else.

Now I can run it with

```
$ ./my_main
Hello C World
```

---

Things I changed compared to your code:

- You need to include `extern "C"` in your Rust function definition
- Add a `\n` to your `printf` (not really relevant to your question, though, just a general fix)
- Make the `char* string` `const` to fix the const conversion warning
- Specifiy the library **after** main.c in your `gcc` command line. gcc linking is sensitive to ordering!! You need to specify `main.c` **first**, and then the `-lhello_c_world` later.

---

I tried the same on Windows. I don't have `gcc` on Windows, so here's how it works with `clang`. `clang` and `gcc` have a very similar command line, though, so it should simply work if you replace `clang` with `gcc`.

- `lib.rs`: same as above
- `Cargo.toml`: same as above

This creates `target/release/hello_c_world.lib`

- `main.c`: same as above

Compile:

```
clang -L./target/release/ -o my_main main.c -lhello_c_world
```

```
>./my_main
Hello C World
```

Comment: I would like to recommend [cbindgen](https://github.com/mozilla/cbindgen) it creates C/C++11 headers for Rust libraries which expose a public C API. 
Could be useful when dealing with complicated projects.